# Implemented a html tag with typo3, but cant find it anymore

Tags: html, web, constants, typo3, typoscript

So i tried out a chatbot for my website. For that i implemented the html code into my website using typo3. I implemented the code into the "setup" or "constants" section. Everything worked perfect.

Now i want to delete that chatbot again. But for the love of god, i cant find that code snipped anymore. Its nowhere to be found. Yet, the chatbot still works on my website. But whats the source?

Tried the search function from typo3. Didnt showed me any results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you search for it in the TypoScript Object Browser as well? There you have all implemented things in one place and you can find it very fast.

Comment: As this kind of code is mostly just some javascript to include another JS-lib and execute it to insert the required HTML, it also could be a HTML content element.

Answer (score 1):

go the to the `template` module and select the `Template Analyzer` from the dropdown on top.

then select view `complete TS Listing`

then use your in browser search function (`ctrl`-`f`) to look for the chatbot code.

this should reveal the code. and you should see which file / or database record it belongs to because of the comments inserted before each include.

Comment: Im not even kidding. The code is not there! Its nowhere to be found. Yet the website still shows the chatbot.

Comment: 1. in the page tree you should select the page where your chat bot is visible. 2. in the TSOB set the conditions according to the page. | otherwise you see a typoscript applied to another page or under other conditions, which might not include the code of the chatbot. | also be sure the search for the correct code. often there is just a javascript to include some remote code and change the content of the page.